# Android Keystore returns a null value when trying to access the saved value

Tags: java, android, android-keystore

My Objective is to save a small String ID in the android Keystore and get it back. This should work even after reinstalling the app. My code as bellow. When I use the "getStringFromKeyChain" method it always returns me a null value. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class KeyChainHelper {

 private static final String ALIAS = "some_uuid";
 private static final String KEYSTORE_PROVIDER = "AndroidKeyStore";

 public static void saveStringToKeyChain(String data) {
    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_PROVIDER);
        keyStore.load(null);
        System.out.println("exe...");
        // Delete the existing key entry with the same alias
        if (keyStore.containsAlias(ALIAS)) {
            System.out.println("HAve...");
            keyStore.deleteEntry(ALIAS);
        }

        byte[] keyBytes = data.getBytes();
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        keyStore.setKeyEntry(ALIAS, secretKey, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Handle error
    }
  }

//This is where the issue i guess 
public static String getStringFromKeyChain() {
    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_PROVIDER);
        keyStore.load(null);

        SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(ALIAS, null);
        if (secretKey != null) {
            byte[] secretKeyBytes = secretKey.getEncoded();
            return new String(secretKeyBytes);
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Handle error
     }
     return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Was an exception thrown?

Comment: @user207421 i get java.security.KeyStoreException: Protection parameters must be specified when importing a symmetric key